# How to map the current host directoy to a Docker container on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm looking for an easy way to map the current directory when you start a docker container on Windows.

I know that you have to use the version, but you have to create it manually.

Normally you use the full "cygwin-ified" version to the current directory:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/username/currentdirectory:/currentDir imageName
```

The problem is that you have to "convert" the directory from `C:\Users\username\currentdirectory` manually.

Is there a way to avoid this manual conversion? I'm trying to create a .bat that won't depend on the hard coded  path

I'm looking for some syntax or utility that will allow me to do something like:

```
docker run -v cygwinfy(.):/currentDir imageName
```

Comment: does `%CD%` work? e.g `docker run -v %CD%:/currentDir imageName`. I don't normally use docker on windows, so I can't test at the minute.

Comment: No  :-( ,   you have to replace  the drive letter  with /c   and all the \  by /    thanks

Comment: Ah, hang on - doesn't cygwin let you do bash i.e. doesn't the normal `$(pwd):/currentDir` work?

Comment: No, pwd  gives you the current directory but in the "unix" format /home/username/currentdirectory

Comment: OK, I'm lost, I thought that was more or less what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the effort...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution to your problem is to implement one of the following variables. Run the following code and you will get a feel for what will be output:

```
@echo off
echo %cd%
cd C:\
echo %cd%
echo %~dp0
pause
```

The %cd% outputs the current working directory, while the %~dp0 outputs the path to the .bat file you are executing.

Comment: Thanks, I still need to "convert" the drive letter  to  /c   and all the back-slashes to forward-slashes